# Как отобразить таблицу в Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Прошу совета, если есть у кого опыт, как отобразить данные таблиц SQLite в виде таблицы, с заголовком, таблицей и, возможно, подвалом.
`ListView` настроить можно, наверное, даже если поместить его в горизонтальный `ScrollView` - должно работать, но остается открытый вопрос с заголовком таблицы и подвалом.
Посмотрел библиотеки на Android Arsenal... к ним есть несколько вопросов. Нет обработчиков нажатия, но не это самое страшное, они не работают с аналогами адаптеров... т.е. надо всю таблицу базы данных выводить сразу, т.е. пихать ее всю в память телефона, что не есть гут.

Comment: Я делал обычный ListView, шапка отдельный layout. Вопрос только в том чтобы задать одинаковый размер столбцов сверху и снизу - либо в dp задать, либо высчитать программно пропорционально размеру экрана.

Comment: вот с размерами то и вопрос. не хотелось бы dp юзать, но,видимо, другого способа нет

Comment: почему нет-то ? можно задать в весах, можно программно рассчитать пропорционально экрану. Ну т.е. грубо в onCreate получаем ширину экрана/делим на кол-во столбцов - получаем ширину столбца - задаем ее в шапке и передаем  в Адаптер, при создании view - задаем параметры.

Comment: относительно не получится, количество столбцов динамическое и может быть довольно большим...
страшно представить как будет выглядеть таблица с 20 колонками на экране :)
тут только жестко прописывать ширину колонок и класть листвью в скроллвью горизонтальный… ну, как вариант…